# injecting child component into parent distorts the style

Tags: angular

I have asked this before and others did but for the life of me, I still can't fix it. Here is a stackblitz for you to see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpcbxm

which is pretty descriptive. I honestly have read a lot about view encapsulation and how it affects injected child components but the 3 settings didn't change anything (nor I want to mess with it in the first place). I tried doing it via selector: '[hello]' then ..... as well but it changes nothing.

I notice a lot of styles are inserted such as ng_content-c4, c6... while I don't know why the child component would have different values than others, I do get they are internal.

In the angular encapsulation page, I did see about styling such components [_ng_content-c6] etc but they are applied to different elements of the child component at a given time that I don't know what to style nor what style to define for them since the style I need is defined for them.

Can someone take a look and help me fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't  get it. What do you specifically need?

Comment: @JoseGuzman have you seen my blitz code and how the <hello> component is not styled as other items of the parent component? When injected into parent component, I want it to be styled as the other elements in the parent component which share its css style definition and of course, for it to be expanded and collapsed on click as well.

Comment: Have you tried disabling style encapsulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to apply the styles defined on the parent to the child component by disabling style encapsulation.

On Parent:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

and also

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

I'm getting some erros on the Blitz you share, but at least styling is working.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4grbtd

Comment: Oh I was trying that on the child component only; I guess I misunderstood a tutorial I was reading about encapsulation about. Just curious...the addExpandClass doesn't get fired for the child component (i.e. it doesn't expand). Any workaround that one?

Comment: oh sorry. I thought it was working fine but you can just edit your blitz that is working fine.

Comment: I doesn't get fired because that method only exist on the parent, not on the child. For communication between componentes take a look a this article https://seegatesite.com/tutorial-call-parent-function-from-child-in-angular-4/
BTW, if my answer solves your initial issue, please consider to mark it as a solution ;)